# How to Adjust the "Type" of Outputted Value in Mongo View

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pipeline

According to how I understand the mongo documentation, the `$trunc` operation should take a number like `9.25` and return `9`:

```
{ _id: 1, value: 9.25 }

db.samples.aggregate([
   { $project: { value: 1, truncatedValue: { $trunc: "$value" } } }
])
The operation returns the following results:

{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 9.25, "truncatedValue" : 9 }
```

If that's the case I'm trying to understand why I'm getting this as a result of my $trunc operation: `98.0`

Why is this resolving as `98.0` rather than just as `98`? And what can I do to remove the `.0` from the result?

I am generating a Mongo view, for which the full pipeline step looks like this:

```
{
  "daysAcc": {
    "$trunc": {
      "$divide": [{
        "$subtract": [new Date(), '$visit.dateOfInit']
      }, 86400000]
    }
  }
}
```

Again, all my resolved values look like this: `98.0`, `32.0`, `145.0`, etc. I just want `98`, `32`, `145`.

I have read that by default the Mongo shell treats floating-point numbers as `double` type by default. This would appear to be the issue. How can I override this type assignment in the pipeline operations included above?

Comment: can you reproduce this in a MongoDB shell? Can you also add th js code you're using to print the results ?

Comment: Not sure that would help, because we know what's happening. According to the mongo documentation, "double" is the default 
assignment type. That's what's being assigned here - so I'm getting 23.0 instead of 23. The question is how can I adjust the type?